# Combine strings and separate them by another string at specific locations

Tags: c#, sql, string, logical-operators

I have nine strings which either are a SQL query or just empty (""), depending on the state of several checkboxes. I need to combine them in another string like

```
string OP = "AND";
string query = "select * from table where " + string1 + OP + string2 + OP + string3 + OP + ... + " order by ID;"
```

The problem is, in between of the strings, I need to have an `AND` or an `OR`. But if any of the strings are empty, it gives me a SQL error. SQL doesn't understand something like

```
select * from table where AND a = "adsf" AND AND AND z = "fghj" AND order by ID;
```

it has to look like this:

```
select * from table where a = "adsf" AND z = "fghj" order by ID;
```

Comment: **Don't use raw SQL.** At the very least, use [*parameterized queries*](http://blog.divergencehosting.com/2009/04/09/using-parameters-parameterized-queries-database-interactions-cshar-vbnet/). Otherwise you're vulnerable to SQL injection and messy, error-prone command concatenation code.

Comment: What does your code look like?  Let's start with that and work from what you've got.

Comment: You know, you should probably provide parenthesizing since you could be mixing operators. Also, you should be using stringbuilders here. Also, don't do this: it's unsafe (unless you absolutely control all the values). Even then: use parameters queries (a.k.a Prepared Statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the strings in an array, remove the empty strings, and combine them using `Join`:

```
string[] conditions = new string[] {
  string1,
  string2,
  string3,
  string4
};

string op = " and ";
string query =
  "select * from table where " +
  String.Join(op, conditions.Where(c => c.Length > 0)) +
  "select * from table where ";
```

And for framework 3.5 change to:

```
  String.Join(op, conditions.Where(c => c.Length > 0).ToArray()) +
```

Comment: seems to be the nicer solution, but throws me an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<c>' to string[]."
but the other one also works fine. thank you :)

Comment: @daydr3amer: Oh, you are using an older framework. Then you need to add `.ToArray()` after the `Where()`. There is no overload of `Join` that takes an enumerable in your version.

Answer (score 1):

```
string query =
   "select * from table where "
   + string1 
   + String.IsNullOrEmpty(string2) ? " " : (OP + string2)
   + String.IsNullOrEmpty(string3) ? " " : (OP + string3)
   + ...
   + " order by ID;"
```

Comment: Yeah. But. Seriously, ***don't du this***. Use prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

Test for Null

```
string query = "select * from table where " + 
String.IsNullOrEmpty(string1) ? "" : (string1+OP) + 
String.IsNullOrEmpty(string2) ? "" : (string2+OP) + 
...+
String.IsNullOrEmpty(string9) ? "" : string9;


//in case your string ends with AND which will if `string9` is empty
if (query.EndsWith("AND"))
{
    int andIndex = query.LastIndexOf("AND");
    query = query.Substring(0, andIndex);
}

query = query + " order by ID;"
```